# Sending one broken taxi each to three different airports.

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, proof-verification, permutations

> Suppose we have $9$ taxis, and three airports, aiport $A$, airport $B$, and airport $C$. We want to send $3$ taxis to airport $A$, $5$ taxis to airport $B$, and $1$ taxi to airport $C$. If exactly three of the taxis are in need of repair, what is the probability
>   that every airport receives one of the taxis requiring repairs?

I'm struggling to solve this problem. There is a theorem that I want to use, listed below:

> **THEOREM**: The number of ways of partitioning $n$ distinct objects into $k$ distinct groups containing $n_1, n_2, \ldots , n_k$ objects, respectively, where each object appears in exactly one group and $\sum_{i=1}^k n_i = n$, is $$N = {n\choose n_1 \;n_2 \;\cdots\; n_k} = {n!\over n_1!\;n_2!\;\cdots\;n_k!}.$$

The following is a solution [I found here](http://www.varsityfield.com/uploads/1/3/0/5/13050122/chapter21.pdf) on page 83 for this problem.

**SOLUTION**: Using the theorem, there are $${9\choose 3\;5\;1} = {9!\over 3!\;5!\;1!} = 504\text{ ways}$$ to send the taxis to *all* the airports. Let $W$ denote the event that the $3$ taxis that are in need of repair are sent to each airport. The number of ways we can send each of the $3$ broken taxis to the three airports is given by $${3\choose 1\;1\;1} = 3! = 6. \tag{Why is this important?}$$ Also, the number of ways we can send the remaining $6$ taxis to the three airports is given by $${6\choose 2\;4\;0} = {6!\over2!\;4!} = 15$$ (since each of the three broken taxis are already taking up a spot). So, by the $mn$-rule, the number of points in the sample space for $W$ is given by $$N_W = \underbrace{6\times15}_\text{Why?} = 90.$$ Thus the probability that each of the three airports receives a broken taxi is $$P(\text{broken taxi to each } A,B,C) = {N_W\over N} = {90\over504}.$$

---

Can someone please explain the two *Why*s? I thought that by holding each of the three broken taxis constant that we would only need to consider the remaining $6$, and I originally thought the probability would be $15\over504$. However, this probability seems *unusually low*. Thus, I went and found the solution written above. However, I was not able to comprehend the logic behind the solution.

Here's what I'm thinking is wrong with my logic process and how we get the correct logic: *Holding* each of the broken taxis to a **particular** airport is where the logic is incorrect. We also want to be able to permute the broken taxis among the three airports. This is why we need the ${3\choose1\;1\;1}$. We can then permute the remaining $6$ taxis among the three airports, giving us the ${6\choose 2\;4\;0}$. Is this correct thinking?

---

An earlier problem asked us to find the probability that **exactly one** broken taxi is sent to airport $C$. I did the following approach:

If we're sending $1$ broken taxi to airport $C$, then we can permute the remaining $8$ like so $${8\choose 3 \; 5\; 0} = 56,$$ which *this* answer was correct according to the back of the book. However, I applied the same principle to the problem at-hand and only received $15$ ways. Is the "correct" way to use the theorem and the $mn$-rule to say: There is $${1\choose 0\;0\;1} = 1$$ way to send $1$ broken taxi to airport $C$, and $56$ ways to distinctly send the other $8$ to airports $B$ and $C$. So, by the $mn$-rule, there are $1\times56$ sample points such that a broken taxi gets sent to airport $C$. This makes sense to me, but I might just be making up a solution that yields the correct answer, but is not logically correct.

Comment: Let $x$, $y$, $z$ denote the broken taxis and say we use ordered triples to represent which broken taxi went to airports A/B/C respectively. Then the 6 in the first "why" counts the following ordered triples $(x,y,z)$, $(x,z,y)$, $(y,x,z)$, $(y,z,x)$, $(z,x,y)$, and $(z,y,x)$.

Comment: Then the other 6 "non-broken" ones need to be sent to the airports with 2 needing to go to airport A (1 broken taxi is already going there) and 4 going to airport B (1 broken taxi is already going there). The number of ways to do this is counted by the 15. Then, the 6 x 15 is the multiplication principle of counting (fundamental principle of counting) - i.e., (number of ways to send the broken ones) $\times$ (number of ways to send the non-broken ones)

Answer (score 1):

Without using fancy formulas you can get the answer by simple enumeration.

There are 3 broken taxis that need to be distributed amongst 3 airports.  We have been given how many taxis that need to go to each airport.

By simply distributing the broken taxis like the below:

3 to the A, 0 to B and 0 to C:  this can be done in ${3\choose3}{5\choose0}{1\choose0} = 1$

2 to A, 1 to B and 0 to C : ${3\choose3}{5\choose0}{1\choose0} = 15$

2 to A, 0 to B and 1 to C : ${3\choose2}{5\choose0}{1\choose1} = 3$

1 to A, 2 to B and 0 to C : ${3\choose1}{5\choose2}{1\choose0} = 30$

1 to A, 1 to B and 1 to C : ${3\choose1}{5\choose1}{1\choose1} = 15$

0 to A, 3 to B and 0 to C : ${3\choose0}{5\choose3}{1\choose0} = 10$

0 to A, 2 to B and 1 to C : ${3\choose0}{5\choose2}{1\choose1} = 10$

Total would be 84 (${9\choose3}$.

What you want is 1 to each airport and that is 15.

Thus the required probability is $\frac{15}{84} = \frac{90}{504}$ from your method.

Thanks

Comment: Sure. This approach is possible because the numbers are small that allows the enumeration. But this enumeration approach has a "scalability" issue. The approach outlined by the OP can be scaled directly. For example, say we have 10 airports, 150 taxis, 30 are broken, taxis sent to the 10 airports are respectively $\{12,18,10,20,15,15,15, 2, 8, 35\}$, find the probability that the broken taxis were sent respectively as say $\{4,2,1,5,3,3,5,1,2,4\}$. The OP's solution can be replicated in this case rather quickly.

Comment: Fully understood, but sometimes if the numbers are manageable, we can use the above method

Comment: But the OP's question asks to explain the steps he/she doesnt understand. So this is an alternative approach, not an answer to their specific question.

Comment: I thought that is exactly what you did in your comments. No worries.

Answer (score 1):

The first *Why* can be interpreted as: there are 6 different ways to send the 3 broken taxis so that each of them end up at different airport. For example, if your broken taxis are 2, 3, 7, then taxi 2 can go to airport B, taxi 3 to airport C, and taxi 7 to airport A. It can easily be seen that there are 6 different arrangements for this scenario, even just by permutation (3 airports for taxi 2 to end up, then 2 airports for taxi 3, then 1 airport for taxi 7).

The second *Why* can be interpreted exactly as you mentioned: holding each of the three broken taxis constant (meaning we know exactly which airport they ended up), how many taxi-to-airport arrangements there are for the remaining 6 working taxis.

Lastly, since there are 6 different ways that the 3 broken taxis can end up (as seen from the first *Why*), each with 15 different ways that the remaining 3 working taxis can end up, the total number of arrangements will be 6 * 15 = 90. In other words, the answer of 15/504 is wrong because it does not take into account the 6 different arrangements that the bad taxis can end up.